# Reading all the data from a UDP socket

Tags: python, sockets, udp

### Situation:

I have a sendersocket which is bound to localhost UDP port 33100.
I have a receiversocket socket bound to localhost UDP port 33101.

The sender socket sends 4500 bytes of data (the string "hello man" * 500). On the receiver side, I have an epoll object which waits for the EPOLLIN event on the receiversocket. When there's an event, I do:

```
while True:
    msg_received = receiver_socket.recv(128)
    if msg_received.decode("UTF-8") == "":
        break
    else:
        print msg_received.decode("UTF-8")
```

### Problem:

The *main* problem is that I cannot read again after I have read the first 128 bytes of data. The sender side says it sent 4500 bytes of data as expected.

If the sender sends the same 4500 bytes of data again, the EPOLLIN event is registered again and I read the new string. Somehow, the buffer get's cleared after my first read.

Now even though the sender just sent me 4500 bytes of data, the first `recv` gives me 128 bytes of data and then nothing is `recv`ed after that.

I am probably doing something really stupid so please enlighten me. I want to receive all the 4500 bytes of data.

Comment: tell us what you want to do besides "receive all the 4500 bytes of data"

Comment: I want to receive it and then print it...that's all...just like the code above says...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should always call recv with `65535` (the maximum size of a UDP packet) if you don't already know the size of the packet. Otherwise, when you call `recv`, the entire packet is marked as read and cleared from the buffer, but then only the first `128` bytes are fed to `msg_received`.

**edit**: when(if) you transition to receiving data only across a network, you can use a smaller number for `recv`, as noted in the [Docs](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This question here basically gave the same answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069204/reading-partially-from-sockets
I should probably do some more reading on the topics...

Answer (score 1):

If you know that you'll be getting 4500 bytes of data, you can call `receiver_socket.recv(4500)`

What your code is saying is that the *maximum* bytes to read is 128 with `receiver_socket.recv(128)`

See the [python documentation for sockets](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html)

Comment: I don't know that I will be getting 4500 bytes of data. I could be getting megabytes of data...which is why, just for experimentation, I limited the size of recv to 128 bytes...

Comment: You repeated the number 4500 in your question and didn't say what size of data you were expecting, so I gave you an answer tailored to your question.